# haproxy fails to bind sockets with ssl option

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I am trying to configure haproxy 1.5 on Ubuntu 3.2.0-91-generic as a TLS proxy for plain TCP traffic to a non-TLS server running on the same machine.  The local non-TLS server is running on port 9501, and I want haproxy to listen on port 9500, decrypting incoming TLS connections on that port and forwarding the unencrypted TCP traffic to the server on port 9501.  I'm doing all this on 172.28.11.94, which is a local intranet address that's bound to my eth0 interface.  My haproxy config looks like this:

```
listen  rtt 172.28.11.94:9500
    mode tcp
    bind 172.28.11.94:9500 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/cert.pem
    option tcplog
    server rks 172.28.11.94:9501
```

haproxy reports that this is valid:

```
dlobron@bos-lpjbb:/etc/haproxy$ sudo haproxy -f haproxy.cfg -V -c
Configuration file is valid
```

But when I run haproxy, I get an error:

```
dlobron@bos-lpjbb:/etc/haproxy$ sudo haproxy -f haproxy.cfg -V   
Available polling systems :
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
       select : pref=150,  test result FAILED
Total: 2 (1 usable), will use poll.
Using poll() as the polling mechanism.
[ALERT] 011/114700 (6149) : Starting proxy rtt: cannot bind socket  [172.28.11.94:9500]
```

I verified that my local non-TLS server on port 9501 is fine:

```
dlobron@bos-lpjbb:/etc/haproxy$ telnet 172.28.11.94 9501
Trying 172.28.11.94...
Connected to bos-lpjbb (172.28.11.94).
Escape character is '^]'.
203 WELCOME
```

The warning about select() not working is a little strange, but it seems like it's falling back to poll(), which should be fine.  But I can't figure out why it can't bind to port 9500 when I run it as root, as I'm doing here.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I should have also noted that I tested my certificate file with openssl, and it reports that it's valid and not expired: dlobron@bos-lpjbb:/etc/haproxy$ openssl x509 -in /etc/haproxy/cert.pem -text
Certificate:
etc.

Answer (score 0):

The very helpful guys on the HAProxy mailing list pointed out my problem: the first line of my server stanza is:

```
listen  rtt 172.28.11.94:9500
```

This is telling HAProxy to bind to 172.28.11.94:9500, and then the "bind" line in my config file is telling it to bind a second time to that same point - hence the error.  I changed the first line of the stanza to just:

```
listen  rtt
```

and it's now fine.